# Laravel - add the contents of an HTML file to the top of another one

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I have a working HTML to PDF (wkhtmltopdf) working Laravel website, where the user has the ability to amend a "template" and then export it to a PDF. At the moment, I have had to encode the font to base64, as the apostrophes etc.. were being missed out. This in itself is a huge amount of code, something that I don't want saving in the database.

So, I have the following stored in a blade (style.blade.php) file (shortened for this example):

```
<style>
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src:url("data:font/ttf;base64,AAEAAAARAQAABAAQR1BPU792x2wAAS2AAAASSkdTVUKOOI56AAE/
                  zAAAAHBPUy8y2a6qaQAAyigAAABgY21hcIwYkAAAAMqIAAAAtGN2dCAG9xijAADScAAAAC5
                  mcGdtclpyQAAAyzwAAAblZ2FzcAASABgAAS10AAAADGdseWbADxfjAAABHAAAw2BoZWFk/

....

                  wABAAEAAmxpZ2EADmxpZ2EADgAAAAEAAAABAAQABAAAAAEACAABABoAAQAIAAIABgAMAN
                  YAAgBMANcAAgBPAAEAAQBJ") 
    format('truetype');
  }

  .page-break {
    page-break-after: always;
  }
</style>
```

I would like to "add" the entire contents of the file, to the top of another HTML file.

Any suggestions how I can do this would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: but where the problem is, with laravel itself, with HTML or why you are not managed to do it? can you post the code or the output you are getting? please, elaborate

Answer (score 0):

Use **@include** directive,

> Blade's @include directive, allows you to easily include a Blade view
>   from within an existing view.

Consider u've this view.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>...</title>
   </head>

   <body>
         <p>Anything could be here</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

And you want `include` that font (style.blade.php) here.

So you would have something like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>...</title>
      @include('style')
   </head>

   <body>
         <p>Anything could be here</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Assuming **style.blade.php** stored under **/resources/views/style.blade.php**

> You may refer to https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade for further
>   information about **Including Sub-Views**

Answer (score 0):

You can make your content portable like example:

```
In Views create > content.blade.php
```

Have your file content inside content.blade.php file.

Then simply where-ever you need to call those content you can simply include it using :

```
@include('content') anywhere in between the code and it will act as if its present there.
```

Normally this is quite a simple approach and we use alot when there is repetition of code. for example : `Creating master blade file.
Or creating header, 
footer etc.`